# How do I make a set of images exactly the same hue/darkness as a sample image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-editing, krita, color-match

I have two textures of the same section of straight road - one darker and yellower, but a low resolution, and the other is the correct resolution but much too light.

I need to be able to exactly match the high-res image's darkness & hue to the lower resolution image, and then apply the exact same action to four other (light, high-res) images of the different road intersections and curves.

All five high-res images need to seamlessly match each other and an image that the low resolution image already matches. I can't simply match them to that image because it is effected by an un-measurable light source, so I have to match them to the low-res image.

(I'd prefer a way of doing this in Krita but I have old Photoshop and I'd use whatever other software you recommend if its free.)

in uploading theses images i must state that i did not create them, the originals are by [curiousb](https://curiousb.dreamwidth.org/30634.html) and the darker image is by [rensim](https://rensim.dreamwidth.org/21495.html)

[image: low res image with correct hue/darkness]
[image]

these are the colour differences when i use photoshop's match colour
[image]

since the difference is quite noticeable is there any automated way to reduce the difference or must it be done manually?

thank you!

Comment: Same images would probably help.

Comment: In Photoshop try: Image>>Adjustments>>Match Color. It will get the source colors and make the second file match that colors.

Comment: is match colour the most accurate method? because it creates noticeable colour differences between the high-res images when i apply it to them.

Comment: @LeoNas don't answer in the comments, use the "Your answer" field at  the bottom

Answer (score 1):

When using the Image>Adjust>Match Color feature... It may be necessary to remove elements from the source image that are not in the new image. For example, the yellow line in the road will cause the entire other image to have a yellow cast since the other image doesn't have any yellow to try and match it to.

Remove the yellow line from the image, then try the Image>Adjust>Match Color feature again.